# SQL Case average formula output issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, average

Everyone - I could use your help.

I have a SQL where I am checking a column to see if there is an amount. If there isn't I want it to output NULL. If it does I want it to calculate an average. I'm using this case statement and the NULL statement works fine, but my average statement is only spitting out 1 or 0. I've been searching and testing for a few hours with no luck.

```
CASE 
WHEN SUM(z.[SumTarget$]) = 0 THEN NULL
ELSE (1-(SUM(z.[SumBackorder])+SUM(z.[SumStockedOut]))/SUM(z.[CountofNo]))
END [SumAvPerc]
```

I have checked each field in the string by commenting out line 3 and using this instead to make sure the numbers are right coming into the formula, and so far everything checks out.

```
--ELSE SUM(z.[SumStockedOut])
```

Here is a sample of the fields and the output.
**I couldn't post the picture because I need more reputation points :( **

Comment: You can add a link to the picture and someone can add it in for you (but text would be better). I'd guess that the data type of one (all?) of your columns is an integer or some description and you're using a RDBMS that performs integer division on integers, like SQL Server for instance... but I'm just guessing. What are your data types? What RDBMS are you using? Can you provide a minimal example that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: is the problem with integer math vs decimal math.  if values are integer to begin with the result will be rounded.  If the values are decimal to begin with they will not be. Example: 3/2 = 2 while  3/2.0 = 1.5  I believe it has to do with how the system interprets the data type for the column being returned.  Since all values involved are integer, it assumes integer return (which isn't decimal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server only does integer division on intgers, so you should convert your values to non-integer numbers.

I often do this using `* 1.0`, something like:

```
(CASE WHEN SUM(z.[SumTarget$]) <> 0 
      THEN (1-(SUM(z.[SumBackorder])+SUM(z.[SumStockedOut]))/SUM(1.0 * z.[CountofNo]))
 END) as [SumAvPerc]
```